# Codeigniter + Doctrine architecture

Tags: codeigniter, doctrine

I am building a system based on Codeigniter + Doctrine.
The system will have three access points.

Backend side, Customer Side and Websevice Side. (Each side is a CI application folder)

I am creating the CRUDS under the Backend/models

I want to reuse it in the other CI applications folders.

What is the best architecture for that?

Should i make it loosely coupled in the webservice side and let the other apps connect to it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each is a seperate CI application?  Seems a little extreme, seeing as components of one could be used by others (eg. libraries, models, etc). I would recommend making it more modular, check out [Modular Extensions - HMVC](http://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home).